# How can I fix the error indexing the maximum in an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get the indexes of the maximums in an array, and put them into another array.
'spc' is an array of 1994736 elements, that shows (around) 400 peaks periodically, and I'm trying to get the indexes of the odd-numbered peaks.
'x' is the period of the peaks.
I wrote this:

```
pms=np.zeros(201)
for k in range(1,200):
    pms[k]=np.where(spc==np.max(spc[(l>x*(2*k-1)-1000)&(l<x*(2*k-1)+1000)]))[0][0]
```

Once I run the code I obtain the following error:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 1994736 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1996776
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you provide us a minimum working example? We need at least test values for the variables spc, x and l

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems weird!
you want to find all peakes with this function:

```
spc[(l>x*(2*k-1)-1000)&(l<x*(2*k-1)+1000)]
```

using np.where

now, you want to find the max of elements that the "where" has found.

Correct?

So, this should be sth like:

```
np.maximum(np.where ....)
```

Please ask your question in a clear way. Based on what you told, I think your method is wrong.

Comment: I only wanted the indexes of the peaks, not the value of them. Anyway, I fixed it, I was using an array 'l' which has a different dimension from the array 'spc'. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: now check if spc==np.max(spc[(l>x*(2*k-1)-1000)&(l<x*(2*k-1)+1000)])  cause to a real result. maybe it never satisfies and so the np.where is empty. Let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I was using an array 'l' which has a different dimension from the array 'spc'.
Now it works.